# Heroku Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, deployment, gitignore

I am new to Heroku and believe I am following all of the steps outlined on Heroku's website to deploy via node.js – https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs – but despite indications of success, I only see this in the browser when I go to my newly-generated herokuapp.com site.

> Cannot GET /

No errors when executing

```
git push heroku master
```

My Procfile is simply

```
web: node app.js
```

I dont quite understand dynos yet, but there seems to be one running:

> heroku ps
>   === web (1X): `node app.js`
>   web.1: up 2014/07/03 23:55:00 (~ 18m ago)

Then:

> heroku open
>   Opening APP-NAME... done

But https://APP-NAME.herokuapp.com/ just displays the *Cannot GET /* message.

Answer (score 33):

I had my **dist** directory included in my *.gitignore* file so I was not committing dist to my repo and not pushing it to Heroku. Therefore, Heroku could not find any content to serve.

I updated my .gitignore, committed, and pushed, and my app shows up just fine on Heroku now.

Comment: I think `dist` folder will always contain new changes and therefore should not be committed. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 8):

almost 3 years, but I'm answering for reference.

- generally /dist is a build process generated directory, it's temporary and changes a lot while working in our sources, so **/dist is not versioned**.
- on your package.json you can add a script called postinstall with this build process, let's say you have a task in gulp called build...so "postinstall": "gulp build"
- if you manage your project's dependencies in bower too, npm install --save bower and "postinstall": "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install && gulp build"

Just a simple example croped for your package.json

```
{
   "dependencies: {
    "bower":"^1.8.0",
    "grunt":"^1.0.1",
   },
   "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./www.js",
    "build": "grunt dist",
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install && npm run build"
   }
}
```

Obvious you're probably done and better nowadays...I'm just referencing it for next consultings.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have these 2 things in place:

1. In your package.json, include heroku-postbuild line, in my case is like this, (it might change if you need to do more than one install)

```
        "scripts": { 
        "heroku-postbuild": "npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
      },
```

2. In your index.js file, add a condition for production

```
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      app.use(express.static("build"));
      app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,  "build", "index.html"));
      });
    }
```

Express  will serve up production assets
like our main.js file, or main.css file

Finally-  Express looks if the request is for an asset
Express will serve up the index.html file
if it doesn't recognize the route

Answer (score 2):

I would think you haven't added the files to git. Whatever file you've edited on your local machine, you need to `git add xyz.ext`, `git commit -m "Message"`, `git push heroku master -u` (`-u` will save the 'heroku master' parameters so future additions you will only need to type `git push`).
In short, every time you're asked to deploy the app, you need to `git add`, `git commit`, `git push`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why it worked but i changed the location of my angular `/dist` from `[root]client/dist` to `[root]/dist` which is at the same directory level as `server.js`

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little bit embarrased but my error was running git push heroku master without the changes being commited.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I finially resolved it.

I had two folders for my code. A server folder with all my backend nodejs file and a client folder for all the front end file. That is the issue from the very beginning.

I `git init` in the server folder, then `git commit` and `git push`. It didn't give me any error in the build but in the `heroku logs` it shows ***404***.

After research for 5 hours, I figure `Heroku Cannot GET /` means it can't access the front end file becuase I only deployed the server folder (Duh!).

I got rid of the server folder and moved all my backend file to the same level with client folder, changed some client file path. redid the `git init` , `git commit`, `git push`. Boom! everything works as expected!

So make sure your server files are in the same level with the client folder and deploy the entire code folder.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In my case I built the front end and served it as a static file in express(backend), the clue was to push the new files to heroku because heroku only had my backend code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these two lines in server.js worked for me:

`var distDir = __dirname + "/dist/";
 app.use(express.static(distDir));`

My dist structure is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and ultimately my problem was that the path I was sending to `express.static()` was wrong because of my directory structure.

I was able to figure that out by logging out the path and then fixing it.