# 'Cannot GET' error while following RubyOnRails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloud9-ide

While following the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#uid100) I successfully `git push heroku master`. However I don't get the same output as the author - he sees the same "hello world" text that I see in my c9 environment. But I only get the following error:

`Cannot GET /devonparsons/rails-tutorialasdofne.herokuapp.com?_c9_id=livepreview1&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io`

Due to the vague naming of this error it's kind of hard to troubleshoot. As far as I can tell by googling, `Cannot GET` is a result of there not being anything TO get. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566635/heroku-cannot-get) question states the problem might be with your .gitignore file, so I tried commenting out some lines there, but it did not help.

I noticed that it the error string is mashing my 'random' subdomain (asdofne) against "rails-tutorial", which looks wrong, but I don't know what it means.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: can you run "heroku logs" in your console and post the results?

Comment: heroku logs here: http://pastebin.com/kMuBL3xD

Comment: @DevonParsons That log does not contain the error in question.

Answer (score 3):

I have gone through your `heroku logs` result and noticed that URL of your heroku application doesn't append with `http://`.
You need to append your heroku app url `asdofne.herokuapp.com` with `http://`

Results `https://asdofne.herokuapp.com`

Answer (score 0):

The link looks funny. I remember that this happens when I create an HTML link and then forget to prepend it with http://. Could it be that something like that happened? It looks like it's taking a, what's supposed to be absolute url, and turning it into a relative one.