# Heroku CANNOT /GET

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Node.js Api to Heroku, but after I deploy it, I get `Cannot GET /` on the `APPNAME.herokuapp.com`

Here is my `app.js` file.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Hello World");
});
```

This works locally when I use port 3000, but I feel like the issue may be pertained to the ports not being configured for production.

Does anybody know what i'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the value of process.env.PORT? Have you tried APPNAME.herokuapp.com:3000?

Comment: herokuapp.com:3000 doesn't work! What should I set instead of process.env.PORT?

Comment: You don't seem to have setup route for `/` . All the routes you have starts with `/api` so try *appname.heroku.com/api*

Comment: The message `Cannot GET /` is actually message from express so your app works there's just no route defined for `/`

Comment: Or if process.env.PORT is not defined, try appname.heroku.com:3000/api

Comment: So if I added `app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('test');
});` it should change?

Comment: I tried `appname.heroku.com:3000/api`, but it says `appname.herokuapp.com refused to connect.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku Cannot GET /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566635/heroku-cannot-get)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an index route `app.get("/").`
Heroku will look for an index route to display and once it cannot find it, it will display the error message `Cannot Get /.` Meaning it cannot get the index route `"/"`. In your code, you seem to have `app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));`. I am assuming you intend this to be your index page, but this isn't how it works. The index page is only the backstroke `"/"`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these two lines in server.js worked for me:

`var distDir = __dirname + "/dist/";
 app.use(express.static(distDir));`

My dist structure is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Heroku needs to look for an index route when loading your app. This is what works for me and I think it will for you too.

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {

    res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        data: {
            name: 'name of your app',
            version: '0.1.0'
        }
    });

});
```