# How can I send `/build` to heroku while keeping generated files out of version control?

Tags: git, heroku, travis-ci

I made an application using `create-react-app`, set up TravisCI, and deployed to Heroku. The application deploys (the server is running, I've shelled in and saw files), but the `/build` folder isn't present.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41837335/2993478), this is because I've listed `/build` in my `.gitignore` file and I can fix the problem by removing that entry; however, [the Heroku dev center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits) recommends against keeping generated files in version control.

Is there a way to mark my `/build` folder as required in production? Am I thinking about this the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is ok to have your `/build` folder added to your `.gitignore` file. When the deployments happens, Heroku will install the app (`npm install`). Make sure that you have the `engines` (node and npm versions) specified in your `package.json`. Also, if you need more flexibility you can use the scripts hooks for `npm install` (`preinstall` and `postinstall`).

You can find all this steps in Heroku documentation: [Getting Started on Heroku with Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#deploy-the-app)

Comment: I forgot to add an `npm install` script. Thanks