# ReactJS APP in Heroku "Invalid Host header" HOST configuration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, webpack, redux

I am trying to put my [React app](https://github.com/gitlwh/MembershipSample/tree/master/client) on the Heroku. The whole project include one API (express) and one client (ReactJS). I have put my API on heroku. But when I put my client on Heroku, it shows build succeeded. But when I [open](https://shielded-temple-31393.herokuapp.com/) it, it shows `Invalid Host header`.

I google this problem and many people tell me to configure the [HOST](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2271). But they are using webpack. I build this with `create-react-app` and I run it by `npm start`. I want to know how to solve this problem in most easy way. Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

If for any reason you were trying to deploy the client without the server, make sure to remove the:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

from the package.json of the client..

***Edit July 2019:***

Create React App 2.0 has changed how we define Proxies.
To determine which version you are using, check your client side package.json: "react-scripts" greater than "2.x.x"

Now in the client/ directory install this package:

```
npm install http-proxy-middleware --save
```

Create setupProxy.js file in client/src/ directory. There is no need to import this file anywhere, CRA looks for a file by this name and loads it.

There are different ways to add proxies:

**Option 1:**

const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware(["/api", , "/otherApi"], { target: "http://localhost:5000" })
  );
};
```

**Option 2**

```
 const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
     
    module.exports = function(app) {
        app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/api/**', { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }));
        app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/otherApi/**', { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }));
    };
```

***Answering to comments***

This proxy is just used in development environment. In production/Heroku everything runs under the same server, so there is not need for Proxy there.

**create-react-app** server just runs in Dev environment, so when the application is run in PROD mode, it is just used to generate the production JS bundle that will be served by the Node/Express server.

Check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566635/heroku-cannot-get/59203812#59203812) for questions on how to make it work in production.

Comment: But how do react send request to backend if you remove the proxy? You explicitly specify the path?

Comment: @Kittichote Kamalapirat I updated my answer to answer your question. I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much, @Roberto. What about if there is the server? For example, Node, React app? You're not supposed to use proxy for that right? Do you have to `run build` in client to create the static files for production?

Comment: Proxies are used just in development mode, where React App is running in one port and Express server in other. In production mode normally everything will run under the same port.

Comment: When I set the proxy URL to my heroku API server, I see "ECONNREFUSED" (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the foreign host.)

Comment: When I follow the instructions above it works in my local dev environment but when deployed to heroku I see a 504 error in browser and in the heroku logs: [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/test-get?id=1 from basic-dm.herokuapp.com to http://localhost:5000 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors).   I have verified that the API service is correctly responding by calling it directly with the heroku URL so it is up and running.  So the proxy through react isn't working

Comment: s2t2 and dam I updated my answer for you guys, I hope it helps.

Comment: @RobertoRodriguez - you are my saviour. I have been fighting this for the past 3 days; Thank you

The edit I would suggest is 

const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/flask/**', { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }));
};

Answer (score 9):

`Invalid Host Header` has been put in as a solution to [DNS Rebinding](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/887).

To solve this, you have to create a file named **.env.development** in the `create-react-app` root folder. Inside this file, set

```
HOST=name.herokuapp.com
```

From the Documentation:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#invalid-host-header-errors-after-configuring-proxy

Comment: Inside the root of the client or the server?

Comment: this cannot solve my issue, my local teriman log: Could not find an open port at name.herokuapp.com.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was happening when I was running the React app in dev mode with webpack. I solved it by setting the value for `allowedHosts` in the `webpack.config.js` file. You can check out [more about the allowedHosts property](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts) from the official webpack documentation.

For my case, I added the following code into `module.exports` of `webpack.config.json`:

```
module.exports = {
    // Some stuff that already exists before
    //.
    //.
    //.
    devServer: {
        allowedHosts: 'all'
    },
}
```

**NOTE:** It is not recommended that you use `all` for the `allowedHosts` property due to security issues. Be sure to specify specific hosts that the app must run on.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was caused by environment variables used in development, not being read in production because the .env file, containing the environment variables, was included in my .gitignore

To solve it, I added the environment variables to the Heroku host.
From Heroku app: **settings** -> **Congif Vars** -> **Reveal Config Vars**

Then add the same environment variables you used in development, here. Once done, the error was gone!

environment variable being used in app

```js
const accessToken = jwt.sign(
      { "userName": foundUser.userName },
      process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: '2h' },
);

const refreshToken = jwt.sign(
      { "userName": foundUser.userName },       
      process.env.REACT_APP_REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: '1d' },
);
```

same environment variable in
[Heroku, Config Vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Bcc.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of code, copy your code into the question with block code format:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @borchvm thanks for the heads up! Response has been updated without images of code. That said, the Heroku Config Vars image was left. Not sure of a better way to include it in the response, other than posting an image, and description. Lmk if there is a better way!