# React project WAR File

Tags: reactjs, deployment, war

I am developing a web-application using React and I want to make a WAR file of the project which should be deployable. I need help if anyone can provide a good resource or maybe help me out?

Comment: Did you use create-react-app ?

Comment: Yes I am using Create-React-App.

Comment: I think this should help you out https://www.megadix.it/blog/create-react-app-servlet/

Answer (score 4):

First, add a pom.xml and make it a maven project and then build it. It will create a War file for you in the target folder after that you can deploy it wherever you want.

### pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    4.0.0
    it.megadix
    my-app
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    war

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <npm.output.directory>build</npm.output.directory>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Standard plugin to generate WAR -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${npm.output.directory}</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                <webXml>${basedir}/web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Required: The following will ensure `npm install` is called
                     before anything else during the 'Default Lifecycle' -->
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install (initialize)</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>npm</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>install</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- Required: The following will ensure `npm install` is called
                     before anything else during the 'Clean Lifecycle' -->
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install (clean)</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>pre-clean</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>npm</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>install</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <!-- Required: This following calls `npm run build` where 'build' is
                     the script name I used in my project, change this if yours is
                         different -->
                <execution>
                    <id>npm run build (compile)</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>npm</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>run</argument>
                            <argument>build</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <CI>true</CI>
                    <!-- The following parameters create an NPM sandbox for CI -->
                    <NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX>${basedir}/npm</NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX>
                    <NPM_CONFIG_CACHE>${NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX}/cache</NPM_CONFIG_CACHE>
                    <NPM_CONFIG_TMP>${project.build.directory}/npmtmp</NPM_CONFIG_TMP>
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                    <configuration>
                        <environmentVariables>
                            <PUBLIC_URL>http://localhost:7001/${project.artifactId}</PUBLIC_URL>
                            <REACT_APP_ROUTER_BASE>/${project.artifactId}</REACT_APP_ROUTER_BASE>
                        </environmentVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                    <configuration>
                        <environmentVariables>
                            <PUBLIC_URL>http://my-awesome-production-host/${project.artifactId}</PUBLIC_URL>
                            <REACT_APP_ROUTER_BASE>/${project.artifactId}</REACT_APP_ROUTER_BASE>
                        </environmentVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Note:- If you find a blank page after running your project then clear your cache or restart your IDE.

Comment: Its not working its giving this error 

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  03:19 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-09T15:19:29+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:exec (npm run build (compile)) on project create-react-app-servlet: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value

Answer (score 1):

If you used **create-react-app** to create your application just add this to your "scripts" section in the package.json:

```
"compile": "npm run build && cd build && jar -cvf web.war ."
```

Then to execute do:

**npm run compile**

It will:

1. Run a Production Build
2. Go to your /build folder
3. Create a war file with the name web.war inside the build folder
   (Put the name you want)

To configure the Proxy to call the server check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54702018/3371954) answer.

Also add this line to your package.json:
**"homepage": "."**

This is how your package.json should look:
...

```
 "homepage": ".",
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "compile": "npm run build && cd build && jar -cvf terminal.war ."
  },
...
```

Comment: `'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`webpack-war-plugin`** to build war file:

Create `.bablerc` and `webpack.config.js` files and their contents in project folder :

**.bablerc**

```
{
   "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const { WebpackWarPlugin } = require('webpack-war-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
       rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(html|css)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new WebpackWarPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        })
    ]
};
```

Add `build war` script and dev dependencies to `package.json` file.

```
"scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "build war": "webpack"
  }

"devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack-war-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1"

  }
```

Run `npm update` to provide dependencies

Then use `build war` script to create `war file`.