# Deploying ReactJS application as .war

Tags: reactjs

Can a react application be deployed as a WAR file... without node. If yes, how?

I got a solution to build the application:
npm run build

and then add it to spring boot application and create war out of it.

Is there any other way out?

Comment: Is the React application entirely client side code (running in the browser only), or does it involve node.js server side code, e.g. for server side rendering of React?

Comment: it has only client side code...

Comment: Then you'll want to serve the js bundle created by webpack as a static resource

Answer (score 0):

Use `webpack-war-plugin` to build war file.

details are described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62384747/11092008