# How to get Data from String format which are getting in success of Login API in retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Kindly read this question, that is asked by me before some hours:
[How is it possible that POST API working in Postman but not the retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60332781/how-is-it-possible-that-post-api-working-in-postman-but-not-the-retrofit/60333289#60333289)

Actually, from Retrofit response, I'm getting response in String format from ResponseBody object.

Explanation: My status code is 200, successful, but from the response body, it is only String. How can I get all data from that String?

After login success, I'm getting String in onResponse. I'm already sending user credential to this APi and in API response, I'm getting this String.

May be there is something encode decode with base64 relation.

Comment: I think you are talking about something similar to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60318634/2583021

Comment: @AtishAgrawal nope dear, My status code is 200, successful, but from the response body, it is only String. How can I get all data from that String?

Comment: is that just bearer/token?

Comment: @Blu nope, there are so many things

Comment: @PoojaSingh i cant find anything else in your output, its just a simple bearer

Comment: @Blu that's what we have to find. This is something AS/AS3 type fomat used in webAPI, we need to parse in JSON and then POJO.

Comment: if you are trying to hit login api, that what a normal response is, you just get a token, nothing else(*sometimes expiry token). you have to save that token for further use...thats a valid responnse, you cant have extra body in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208249/discussion-between-blu-and-pooja-singh).

Comment: @AtishAgrawal See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60370961/what-to-pass-in-cipher-dofinal-in-android-java

Comment: @Blu See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60370961/what-to-pass-in-cipher-dofinal-in-android-java

Comment: @PoojaSingh ohh so its related with encryption

Comment: @Blu umm, later I got to know:P

Comment: @Blu Acha, can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60374479/which-one-is-working-in-androidx-app-typeface-or-android-typeface

Comment: @PoojaSingh your question here was really confusing, didnt even understood that its related with encryption

Comment: @Blu yupppppp....

Comment: @Blu but I wrote this too: May be there is something encode decode with base64 relation.

Comment: @PoojaSingh but stiil no hint or clue about encryption, it didnt even click in mind

Comment: @Blu kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LoginModel {

    @SerializedName("body")
    private Body body;

    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public static class Body {
        @SerializedName("userPwd")
        private String userpwd;
        @SerializedName("prodId")
        private int prodid;
        @SerializedName("emailId")
        private String emailid;
        @SerializedName("customerId")
        private int customerid;

        public String getUserpwd() {
            return userpwd;
        }

        public int getProdid() {
            return prodid;
        }

        public String getEmailid() {
            return emailid;
        }

        public int getCustomerid() {
            return customerid;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in if you followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60333289/7948109) you `retrofit` interface is something like this

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("login/desktop/user")
Call<ResponseBody> getToken(@Body HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> data);
```

change it to

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("login/desktop/user")
Call<LoginModel> getToken(@Body HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> data); // change here
```

Now you can get your data in `onResponse()` like this

```
LoginModel loginData = response.body();

String pswd = loginData.getBody().getUserpwd();
```

**PS** = if you can change the response I suggest you to change var `body` from response to something else like `data`.

`SerializedName` used in `POJO` class are not important, [read more about them here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28957285/7948109)

Hope this will help!

Comment: You understood wrong. After login success, I'll get data in onResponse. I'm already sending user credential to this APi and in API response, I'm getting this String.

Comment: Please show the response of this API in retrofit, a screenshot

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60370961/what-to-pass-in-cipher-dofinal-in-android-java

Comment: @PoojaSingh how is this related?

Comment: it is the same thing. I don't know previously that how to decrypt that string response